# How to make SQL Spark Case Insensitive with field values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I write SQL Spark Commands to return fields with Case Insensitive results?

Example:
Sample_DF below

```
+--------+
|  name  |
+--------+
|  Johnny|
|  Robert|
|  ROBERT|
|  robert|
+--------+
```

It seems by Default it seems Spark SQL is case sensitive via the field you query for:

```
spark.sql("select name from Sample_DF where status like '%Robert%'").show
+------+
|name  |
+------+
|Robert|
+------+
```

What can I do to configure above query to be case insensitive so that it can return below, assuming there is a large list of various roberts of different lower/uppercase variations?

```
+--------+
|  name  |
+--------+
|  Robert|
|  ROBERT|
|  robert|
+--------+
```

As I understand SQL Spark does not support MSSQL Collate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make all characters lowercaser.

```
spark.sql("select status from Sample_DF where lower(status) like '%' || lower('Robert') || '%'").show
```

there is also a builtin function [How to change case of whole column to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500827/how-to-change-case-of-whole-column-to-lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a look at all the names in the name column, you could use the lower function, which converts all chars to lowercase.

```
Sample_DF.select(F.lower('name')).show()
```