# Convert a column of Spark dataframe to lowercase

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, lowercase, apache-spark-dataset, spark-java

How to convert a column value in Spark dataframe to lowercase/uppercase in Java?

For example, below is the input dataframe:

```
name | country | src        | city       | debit
---------------------------------------------
"foo"| "NZ"    | salary     | "Auckland" | 15.0
"bar"| "Aus"   | investment | "Melbourne"| 12.5
```

I need convert the 'city' column to lower case

```
name | country | src        | city       | debit
------------------------------------------------
"foo"| "NZ"    | salary     | "auckland" | 15.0
"bar"| "Aus"   | investment | "melbourne"| 12.5
```

I have found solutions in Scala and Python, but not in Java as below

[How to change case of whole column to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500827/how-to-change-case-of-whole-column-to-lowercase)

In java there is a solution to convert column names, but not its data.

[How to lower the case of column names of a data frame but not its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675036/how-to-lower-the-case-of-column-names-of-a-data-frame-but-not-its-values)

How can I convert column values to lowercase?

Comment: The same function is also available in java. I don't understand which difficulties you're facing exactly?

Comment: how can i use java stream to convert data to lower case instead column ?

Comment: Why do you want to use stream if you only need to lowercase the column `city`?

Comment: I am not sure how can i change the colum to lower case without iterating ?

Comment: `import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower;`  then updating the column in your dataframe: `df.withColumn("city", lower(df.col("city")))`

Comment: oh okay,  I was trying to import function as below which was giving an error.

```import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower;```

Answer (score 0):

incase someone is looking for answer.
Below is the solution as per suggestion by @blackbishop

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lower; 
df=df.withColumn("city", lower(df.col("city")))
```